# Aptana3-> disable autocomplete suggestion

Tags: aptana3

In Aptana3 I am unable to disable tooltips for autocompletion.

How can I disable it?
I have disable all options in Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Completion but that still happend.

[Tooltips (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x8G7.png)

[After ENTER (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5tQB.png)

---

Explanation:

When I write code, it is constantly showing frames with useless content that hide my code and I should use shift+enter instead of enter to insert a new line.

Example:
I want to write:

```
else
{
}
```

The tooltips show me what 'else' is (I think after 14 years programming I know that) and when I push 'ENTER', it directly write:

```
else{

}
```

That is enoying.
I hate auto-completion because:

- It add content that some times I do not see, that mean a bugs in my code.
- It force me to read what I am writting, when I prefer to read documentation.
- It do not take care about my programming style. I may ofc create a new workspace for every one, but it's anoying and time-lost.

Thx you for help.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This auto-completion is called content assist. To disable it in Aptana Studio 3 :

1. Choose Window in the main menu
2. Go to Preferences
3. Choose Aptana Studio → Content Assist
4. Look at the Auto-display content assist . You will see a drop down
   menu
5. Click drop-down menu and choose Off instead of Default delay.